# Find the different lines between two files without sorting

Tags: linux, text-processing, bioinformatics

I have two files, file1 is a subset of file2, which means all the lines in file1 can be found in file2 but some lines in file2 are not in file1. Now I want to find the different lines(or extra lines) between two files. Because of the content(contains long RNA sequences) of the file, it's not very feasible to sort the file, so I'm wondering if I can find the extra or different lines between two files without sorting.

I tried this command, but seems not working:

```
    grep -vxFf barcodes1.tsv barcodes.tsv > diff.csv
```

Below is a section of file1 ( which have 6113 lines):

```
AAACCTGAGAAAGTGG-1
AAACCTGAGCCACGCT-1
AAACCTGAGCCTATGT-1
AAACCTGAGCTGCAAG-1
AAACCTGCATTCGACA-1
AAACCTGCATTGGGCC-1
AAACCTGCATTTCACT-1
AAACCTGGTAACGTTC-1
AAACCTGGTATTCGTG-1
AAACCTGGTCGGCACT-1
AAACCTGTCACTATTC-1
AAACCTGTCAGGCGAA-1
AAACCTGTCCTAGTGA-1
AAACCTGTCGGATGTT-1
AAACCTGTCTGATTCT-1
AAACGGGAGTGAACAT-1
AAACGGGCACTCTGTC-1
AAACGGGGTAAGAGAG-1
AAACGGGGTACCTACA-1
AAACGGGGTTCAGACT-1
AAACGGGGTTTGACTG-1
AAACGGGTCAAAGTAG-1
AAACGGGTCAACCAAC-1
AAACGGGTCATGCATG-1
AAACGGGTCCTATTCA-1
AAACGGGTCGTATCAG-1
AAACGGGTCTATGTGG-1
AAAGATGAGCACAGGT-1
AAAGATGAGCAGGCTA-1
AAAGATGCAAACTGTC-1
```

Below is a section of file2(which have 6121 lines):

```
AAACCTGCAAGCGAGT-1
AAACCTGCACACAGAG-1
AAACCTGGTAAACACA-1
AAACCTGGTCGGATCC-1
AAACCTGGTCTCTTTA-1
AAACCTGGTTTAAGCC-1
AAACCTGTCAACACCA-1
AAACCTGTCTATCCCG-1
AAACCTGTCTTTAGGG-1
AAACGGGAGCCACCTG-1
AAACGGGAGCGTTTAC-1
AAACGGGAGCTGTTCA-1
AAACGGGAGTAGGCCA-1
AAACGGGAGTGCCATT-1
AAACGGGCAACACCTA-1
AAACGGGCAATAGCGG-1
AAACGGGCACAGATTC-1
AAACGGGCACAGTCGC-1
AAACGGGCAGATGAGC-1
AAACGGGCAGGAATCG-1
AAACGGGCAGGTCCAC-1
AAACGGGCAGGTGGAT-1
AAACGGGCATAAAGGT-1
AAACGGGGTAGCTCCG-1
AAACGGGGTAGCTGCC-1
AAACGGGGTTCAACCA-1
AAACGGGGTTTGGGCC-1
AAACGGGTCAAACAAG-1
AAACGGGTCGAACTGT-1
AAACGGGTCTTAACCT-1
```

It's not feasible to sort these two files. Therefore, what the command will be to the job without sorting?

Comment: @K7AAY edited the answer already.

Comment: Don't mean to be argumentative, but sorting 7,500 lines of 80 characters each on my five year old desktop, which has a 4th Generation i7 at 4GHz, took less than a second, so an answer dependent on sorting may be very reasonable.

Comment: @K7AAY time is not the problem, the problem is how to sort it based on the RNA sequences? Actually the files content I posted at the answer already sorted using "sort", but it's still different.

Comment: There is only RNA sequences in the file, only one column

Comment: Why does it seem that `grep -vxFf` is not working? Given your examples and `grep -vxFf file1.tsv file2.tsv > diff.tsv` results in `file2.tsv` and `diff.tsv` having the same content, because **all lines are unique**. Maybe you should [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/522229/edit) your question and provide better sample data and tell us why `grep` doesn't work.

Comment: How to sort based on the RNA sequence? _sort originalfile > sortedfile_

Comment: What do you mean by 'already sorted using "sort", **but it's still different**'? Different in what way? I feel like this is an X-Y problem. Sorting seems the simplest way to go.

Answer (score 1):

This one liner should do the trick, And it takes care that the output file is not sorted:

```
cat -n barcodes1.tsv barcodes.tsv | sort -uk2 | sort -nk1 | cut -f2- > diff.csv
```

Basically, what it does is:

- Concatenates the file.
- Removes the duplicates.
- Outputs in the desired file which won't be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of grep, may I substitute [comm](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36870/comm-1g.html) ? [Tutorials](https://www.howtoforge.com/linux-comm-command/) may be [helpful](https://shapeshed.com/unix-comm/), but here's a one liner to do what you want:

```
comm -3 bigfile smallfile > differences
```

Comment: The command `comm` only works correctly for already "sorted" files (something the title of the question asks "not to do")

Comment: The original poster also commented "Actually the files content I posted at the answer already sorted using "sort", I noted the entire 6,121 line file takes less than a second to sort, which resolved the X,Y problem https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5062/absurdist-humour-in-comments/5063#5063 .